# Error installing Composer on Windows 7

Tags: php, cmd, composer-php

I'm trying to install Composer on Windows 7. When I try to run from CMD, I got an error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
>   \composer.phar" has a broken signature' in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:13
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar(13): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')#1 {main}
>     thrown in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar on line 13.

Please help ... Thanks for answering.

Comment: Delete the `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup` folder and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Delete `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup` folder and run installer again.